# An imprecise external abort, received while the processor enters WFI, may cause a processor deadlock

Tags: deadlock, armv7, mmu

**This is an ARM errata for Cortex A9 processors.**

**Description:-**

An imprecise external abort received while the processor is ready to enter into WFI state might
cause a processor deadlock.
Explicit memory transactions can be completed by inserting a DSB before the WFI instruction.
However, this does not prevent memory accesses generated by previously issued PLD instructions
page table walks associated with previously issued PLD instructions or as a result of the PLE
engine.
If an external abort is returned as a result of one of these memory accesses after executing a WFI
instruction, the processor can cause a deadlock.

**So, how to prevent the deadlock by protecting the MMU.**

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't perform the WFI directly after a PLD. But you probably should explain a LOT more about your situation. Are you writing an OS or a user-mode program, to name just the first on many details we'll need.

Comment: **Source : Cortex-A9 Technical reference Manual(ARM)**

 
The micro TLB returns the physical address to the cache for the address comparison, and also checks the protection attributes to signal either a Prefetch Abort or a Data Abort.                                                                                                                                  So,could you please help me how to disable the prefetch/data abort signalling by writing to coprocessor(cp15) using  **MCR Instruction **@Brendan